# Returning static page with url path parameters

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, request-mapping

I have the following controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/room/{roomId:^(?!main.html$).*}")
public class Rooms {

    @RequestMapping
    public String index(@PathVariable(value = "roomId") String id) {
       // do some stuff...
       return "main.html";
    }
}
```

I have a main.html file in my resource/static folder. I would like when a user goes to /room/{something} to do some processing, return the static main.html page I have.

Everything I try results in a page not found exception or

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [main.html]: 
would dispatch back to the current handler URL 
[/room/main.html] again
```

what am I missing to allow this to work?

Thanks for the help

Comment: you added InternalViewResolver in project?

Comment: No. I'm am brand new to this spring stuff. I thought spring was supposed to be able to handle html files without any configuration?  How do I go about adding a internal view resolver?

Comment: Also, If I don't have the URL path parameters and then return main.html, it works fine. There is only an issue when I introduce the URL path parameters.

Comment: Hey! Did you solve this? I am stuck at EXACT same point.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing configuration in class for view resolver

```
@Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver()
    {
        UrlBasedViewResolver res = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        res.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        res.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        res.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return res;
    }
```

If using xml

```
<beans:bean     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Also change your controller by below code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/room/")
public class Rooms {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(@PathVariable(value = "roomId") String id) {
       // do some stuff...

       ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("main");
       return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As soon as I can I will try this out. Couple questions. Why are we setting the suffix to .jsp? My file is main.html. And why would the prefix be WEB-INF/jsp if my html files are in resources/static? Should I move my files? Finally I can certainly change the code to what you provide. However could you explain why return a model and view instead of the string that I had? Thanks

Comment: you can set the .html also.I used .jsp thats why i write.you can change it.Normally jsp file kept in folder which is inside web-Inf.But you can change the location of files also.Its all about configuration.Just mention correct location in configuration file that's it.I have not tried with the method which return String but you can try for that.